# Task Manager Displaying 8.2/12.4 GB of RAM committed when I only have 8 installed

Tags: windows-8, memory

So, as stated in the title, Windows task manager is telling me that 8.2 (or whatever it decides that number is) out of 12.4 GB of RAM is committed when I really only have 2 sticks of 4 GBs each.

[image]

Why is this? I've searched all over the internet but people seem to be having the literal opposite problem I am.

CPU: AMD A10-7850K
Motherboard: ASUS A78M-E
RAM: I have no idea but it's DDR3 clocked at 1600 MHz
GPU: EVGA 1070 SC

Comment: Maybe that number is a pagefile memory and not actually physical RAM?

Comment: Would it be better if I added a screenshot of my Task Manager?

Comment: Yes, I think so

Comment: It has been updated.

Comment: Run > dxdiag it ahould show the page file memory in use. It might  be the same number as the screenshot. That number is probably the virtual memory.

Comment: That it is. Thank you. Care to post that as an answer some how so I can "close" this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commit charge, or "Commit" as shown in Task Manager is difficult to describe in a way that is both technically accurate and still easy to understand. Most explanations I have seen tend toward the easy to understand but at the expense of accuracy.

The Commit is not a measurement of RAM usage, or pagefile usage, or any combination of the two. It is more a matter of potential usage. Essentially applications request the OS for a place to store data. This storage may be in RAM or pagefile. Initially there is no reservation for this storage, just a commitment by the OS that there will be storage available. The commit is simply a total of all such requests for storage. Typically applications will not use all of the storage requested, at least not at the same time. The commit limit is the maximum limit for the commit. It is RAM size + pagefile size - a small overhead.

Understand that this is a highly simplified version of what actually happens.

A high commit does not impact performance. What is important is that the commit never reaches the commit limit. Windows will issue out of memory errors before that happens. If the pagefile is system managed the commit limit is flexible. The OS can make the pagefile larger, up to the defined limit, to expand the commit limit. It will only do this when necessary.

I would suggest you set the pagefile to system managed if disk space allows.